# pass variable from change function

Tags: jquery

I use jquery 1.3.2, I use change function to detect newly selected item from dropdown list. If newly selected value (not :selected in html) equals certain value, I disable submitting a form.

```
$("#edit-status").change(function () {
    if ($('#edit-status').val() == 'package_sent') {
        $("#update-form").submit(function(e) {
            alert('alert');
            e.preventDefault(e);
        });
    };
});
```

This code works but only for the first time, after I click ok on alert, try to change another option and then use submit, I got the same alert even with another option selected. Maybe is it somehow possible to put #edit-status value into variable and use it outside function?

Question: Is it possible to pass variable from change function, so I can use it in evaluation outside function?

Comment: can you share your html too? More helpful if you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Since you're retrieving the value of `#status` in the change function it should reflect the current value. Perhaps something else is wrong. Also, jQuery 1.3?!?!

Comment: Somewhat confusing, the `#edit-status` is the dropdown, but you are checking the value of another element `#status`? That other element won't change just because you change `#edit-status`.

Comment: @Kristoffer sorry I made mistake simlyfying my real code:) the id is the same.